# Очередность хода игроков при игре в карты

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

Пытаюсь написать карточную игру на Javascript , нужна помощь в реализации очередности захода игроков - 4 игрока , первая сдача  первым ходит игрок 1, при каждой следующей сдаче ход начинает следующий игрок:

сдача 2 - игрок 2,
3 - игрок 3,
4 - игрок 4,
5 - снова игрок 1,
ну и тд до окончания партии.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, **в чем именно вы видите проблему**. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Внутри программы нумеруете сдачи и игроков с 0. Номер ходящего игрока = остаток от деления сдачи на 4

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать `return n` если нужны индексы

```html
<script>
  function fn(a) {
    n = -1;
    fn = function() {
      n = ++n % a.length;
      return a[n]
    }
  }
  fn(["one", "two", "three", "four"]);

  for (var i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
    document.write(fn() + " ")
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Что это вообще такое?

Comment: @PavelMayorov видимо ответ на вопрос

Comment: чем не нравится то хоть напишите

Comment: Вы ответили на вопрос, который еще не был сформулирован. Запросто может оказаться, что проблема у автора совсем в другом (к примеру, игра может оказаться клиент-серверной). Или проблема у автора на самом деле не в алгоритме, а в архитектуре.

Comment: Не говорю уже о том, что я лишь со второй попытки понял что вообще код делает, а новичку понять подобный код - без шансов. Вы же не оставили ни одного комментария кроме еще менее понятного *"можно сделать return n если нужны индексы"*

Comment: @PavelMayorov если вам не трудно добавьте коментарии